# MapView is showing Darker map inside Dialog

Tags: android, google-maps, dialog, android-mapview

I am trying to display google map inside dialog window. For this dialog i am using following lines of code:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(SetProfileOnlineActivity.this);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.pick_location_layout);
        Window w = dialog.getWindow();
        w.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        dialog.show();
```

**pick_location_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/myLl"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_map_search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_search_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Search"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
             />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib_search_map"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/search"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/myLl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_map_cancel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/red"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_18sdp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_map_ok"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/green"
            android:text="Ok"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_18sdp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_switch_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="Switch View"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/myLl"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Now my problem is that my map is showing darker. I am also displaying edittext in dialog which is showing perfectly but map is only component which is showing darker as shown in image. So, is there any way to make mapview brighter as other components?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update for MapView**

Solution for `mapView` in `dialog` is removing background dim like this (adjusted for your code, just paste before `dialog.show()`):

```
        w.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
```

Bad part is I've found this solution in [5 year old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14589079/mapfragment-gets-a-dark-overlay-when-used-in-dialogactivity)

**Previous answer**

I've just checked with "*newer map*" solution ([read more here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUtMS.png)):

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    app:mapType="normal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

and it shows bright `--image was here--`

Comment: I can't use fragment because i had done lots of operations with map and now i am just fixing the view. If i use fragment then it will mess up all the operations. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Have you tried adding background to root element in xml? `<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout ... android:background="#FFFFFF">`

Comment: no, i doesn't tried. Let me try it out but which background i should have to add? transperant or any other?

Comment: Transparent is by default, try white `android:background="#FFFFFF"`

Comment: okay..let me try and get back to you soon.Thanks

Comment: Not working man.

Comment: That's strange. I'm testing in Android 7.0 and it shows as it should. What is your device and Android version? Also is there any code that modifies your `mapView` or its style?

Comment: I have tested this app on Redmi 3s having marshmallow , Micromax canvas spark having lolipop and android emulator having naugat. All shows me same result and yes i am using code which modifies map style. When user clicks "switch view" button, map style will changed from normal to satelite view and vice versa. There is no any code which changes mapview style.

Comment: are you using same code which i have posted in my question for testing or you have done any modification in it?

Comment: Check my updated answer, it should solve your problem now.

Comment: Very very very big thanks to you. Updated answer has solved my problem. Thank you.